# FTP upload gives time out, but does upload the file

Tags: c#, monodevelop, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to figure out this element, I have made an ftp module with several actions which all work perfectly, except for the upload method. In fact it does work, but it still returns an error.

So I get a time out error after some time, but when I check on my ftp, the file is added succesfully. So I can't understand this feature..

My Code:

```
public static Boolean upload(string remoteFile, string localFile, string applicatie_url) {
        Boolean returnbool = false;

        try {

            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
            FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
            Stream ftpStream = null;

            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile; // upload

            byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(localFile);
            ftpRequest.ContentLength = b.Length;
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

            try {

                ftpStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                  // Error catching
            }

            // Cleanup
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
            ftpResponse = null;
            returnbool = true;

        } catch (Exception ex) { 
          // Error catching
        }

        return returnbool;
    }
```

My ex.message : 'Transfer timed out.'

My ex.stacktrace : 
 ' '  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00052] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System/System.Net/FtpWebRequest.cs:411 
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System/System.Net/FtpWebRequest.cs:426 
  at AutoPolis.FTPHelper.upload (System.String remoteFile, System.String localFile, System.String applicatie_url) [0x00078] in /Users/.../App_Code/FTPHelper.cs:92 '

Any help would be appreciated. I work on my mac with MonoDevelop as IDE, don't know if this makes any chances to this element..

Comment: is the file upload complete?

Comment: When I check my ftp I can access the file (image in this case) indeed. I can see it without any problems, so no corrupt file or anything like this. Tried with this file http://yosoyke.be/Veloster/Hyundai.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've looked at a few ftp programs in the past and noticed that in your code clean up, you've written ftpResponse = null; but I would go with "ftpResponse.Close();". Your stacktrace seems to mention FTPWebRequest, so this may help!

p.s. this may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class

Comment: Well thx, didn't really closed the response but it was indeed there that the exact error took place. I noticed in my code I didn't needed the ftpresponse, so I could totally delete that part.
 (code was indeed based on the given url !!)